# Clear all Gridview values

Tags: c#, gridview

I need to clear all the old values in gridview
Note: The gridview is not connected to sql db am just using it as view
as i request new data in the same gridview it just overwrites the old cells
so i need to clear all cells before requesting new data in the gridview

am also using visual c# 2010

Answer (score 0):

Just set DataSource to null and call DataBind() on GridView.

Comment: For DataGridView call Rows.Clear() and set DataSource to null

Answer (score 0):

did you try `DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()`? Did you bind it to  datasource?